# LED Flash Light not working in Oreo O 8.0 and above while working in all OS versions below

Tags: java, android

Hello I am developing a LED flash Alert app where the LED will blink while call and sms will receive working in all versions but not working in Android O 8.0 to onward please send any solution.thanks a lot [Almost same as this app Flash Alert](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iodev.flashalerts)

**Flash Alert Class** to turn on and off the flash:

```
package com.flashalert.FLash;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;

public class FlashThread implements Runnable {
    private static Camera cam;
    private static Parameters params;
    private boolean isFinish;
    private boolean isFlashOn;
    private Context mContext;
    private int offLength;
    private int onLength;
    private int times;

    public FlashThread(Context context, int onLength, int offLength, int times) {
        this.isFinish = true;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.isFinish = true;
        this.times = times;
        this.onLength = onLength;
        this.offLength = offLength;
    }

    public boolean isFlashEnable() {
        return this.isFinish;
    }

    public void setFlashEnable(boolean enable) {
        this.isFinish = enable;
    }

    public int getOnLength() {
        return this.onLength;
    }

    public void setOnLength(int onLength) {
        this.onLength = onLength;
    }

    public int getOffLength() {
        return this.offLength;
    }

    public void setOffLength(int offLength) {
        this.offLength = offLength;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.times;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.times = count;
    }

    private void getCamera() {
        if (cam == null) {
            try {
                cam = Camera.open();
                params = cam.getParameters();
                //cam.startPreview();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public void turnOffFlash() {
        if (!this.isFlashOn || cam == null || params == null) {
            Log.e("CallService", "turnOffReturn");
            return;
        }
        try {
            params=cam.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
//            params.setFlashMode("off");
            cam.setParameters(params);
            cam.stopPreview();
            this.isFlashOn = false;
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        }
    }

    public void turnOnFlash() {
        if (this.isFlashOn || cam == null || params == null) {
            Log.e("CallService", "turnOnReturn");
            return;
        }
        try {
            params=cam.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            cam.setParameters(params);
            cam.startPreview();
            this.isFlashOn = true;
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.e("CallService", "thread run");
        getCamera();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < this.times) {
            if (this.isFinish) {
                try {
                    turnOnFlash();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                SystemClock.sleep((long) this.onLength);
                try {
                    turnOffFlash();
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                }
                SystemClock.sleep((long) this.offLength);
                i++;
            } else {
                Log.e("CallService", "break thread");
                turnOffFlash();
                try {
                    cam.stopPreview();
                    cam.release();
                    cam = null;
                    return;
                } catch (Exception e3) {
                    destroy();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            Log.e("CallService", "try break");
            cam.stopPreview();
            cam.release();
            cam = null;
        } catch (Exception e4) {
            Log.e("CallService", "catch break");
            destroy();
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
        try {
            cam.stopPreview();
            cam.release();
            cam = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

**Flash Alert Call Receiver Class** to run LED while on call ringing:

```
package com.flashalert.Receiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import span4u.flashalert.Services.CallService;
//import com.iodev.flashalert.common.PrefUtils;
//import com.iodev.flashalert.common.Utils;
//import com.iodev.flashalert.service.CallService;

public class PhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "PhoneReceiver";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onReceive call");

        if (!intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {
            return;
        }
//        if (Utils.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext()).checkSetup(context.getApplicationContext(), PrefUtils.TYPE_CALL)) {
          try {
              context.startService(new Intent(context, CallService.class).setAction(intent.getAction()).putExtra("incoming_number", intent.getStringExtra("incoming_number")).putExtra("state", intent.getStringExtra("state")));
          }
          catch (IllegalStateException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
// } else {
//            Log.e(TAG, "Receiver return");
//        }

//        if (intent.getStringExtra("state").equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
//            flashThread = new FlashThread(context, 300, 300, 20);
//            flashThread.setFlashEnable(true);
//            new Thread(flashThread).start();
//
//        } else {
//            flashThread.setFlashEnable(false);
//            new Thread(flashThread).stop();
//        }
        //System.out.print("state:call" );

      //  System.out.print("state:" + intent.getStringExtra("state"));
    }

}
```

**My manifest class:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.flashalert">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name=".App"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <receiver
            android:name=".Receiver.MessagingReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter android:priority="5822">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".Receiver.PhoneReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".Services.CallService"
            android:enabled="true"/>
        <service android:name=".Services.MessageService"
            android:enabled="true"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <!-- Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working in Android O 8.0"?

Comment: means flash is not blinking while receiving call and sms .